# fixed width bash prompt

Tags: macos, bash

I'd like to set my bash prompt to a fixed width, and make up the difference in space before the $, so whether long or short, my prompt remains the same width:

```
[name@host] ~/Directory/Dir...Another/LastDir $ 
[name@host] ~/Directory(branch)               $
```

Currently, in a short directory path my prompt looks something like this:

```
[name@host] ~/Directory(branch) $
```

a deeper directory path looks like this:

```
[name@host] ~/Directory/Dir...Another/LastDir $
```

You can see I've truncated the PWD in the middle so I can see where the path begins, and where it ends. I'd like to make up the difference before the $.

Here is my current prompt:

```
# keep working directory to 30 chars, center tuncated
prompt_pwd() {
  local pwd_symbol="..."
  local pwd_length=30
  newPWD="${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
  [ ${#newPWD} -gt ${pwd_length} ] && newPWD=${newPWD:0:12}${pwd_symbol}${newPWD:${#newPWD}-15}
}
# set prompt
prompt_color() {
  PROMPT_COMMAND='prompt_pwd;history -a;title_git'
  PS1="${WHITEONMAGENTA}[\u@\h]${MAGENTA} \w\$(parse_git_branch) ${MAGENTABOLD}\$${PS_CLEAR} "
  PS1=${PS1//\\w/\$\{newPWD\}}
    PS2="${WHITEONTEAL}>${PS_CLEAR} "
}
```

In my search, I found  [A Prompt the Width of Your Term](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-12.html#ss12.6) which does do some fill, but couldn't get it working for this particular prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your path is too short (`[ ${#newPWD} -le ${pwd_length} ]`), you can use printf(1) to extend it.

```
printf -v newPWD "%-*s" $pwd_length "$newPWD"
```

This will left-justify the string in `$newPWD` with a field width of `$pwd_length`.

printf(1) is built into bash so it is not too expensive to run each prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment variable `BASH_COMMAND`, which allows you to define the prompt manually. You may use `expand -t` to get it to the desired length.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is position my directory and such **above** my prompt, so I don't have to worry about it:

```
myusername@mybox:/home/myusername/some/directory
$
```

This way, I can also have the added benefit of copying the line above for SCP and SSH commands without having to prepend the user@host:/directory example.

Here's my $PS1 variable, should you like to try it out:

`\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$`

Comment: i like this, but for true copy and paste to work, i'd want to wrap quotes around any directories with spaces.

Comment: @seaofclouds:  Yeah, that is something that I haven't had to work with too much, but I see where you're coming from.  However, in comparison to typing it all by hand, or editing the few spaces with \, I still think a partial solution is better than nothing.  There's probably a way to annotate that, but I don't know enough about PS1 variables to do that (yet).

Comment: I am trying to use your fix (Ubuntu 12.04). To do this fix, do you edit .bashrc to have: export PS1="\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$"   ? I did this edit then opened up bash again. However, my prompt did not change. Do you happen to know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Depending on the environment, you might have to put that `export PS1=` command in your `.profile` instead of the `.bashrc`, although I'm a little hazy on the details.  At work, I use the `.profile`, at home I use `.bashrc`. YMMV